# Alamofire Error: Operation couldn't be completed. Software caused connection abort

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, alamofire

Alamofire give me an error when I call API and Lock mobile screen or Minimize application.

> **"The operation couldn't be completed. Software caused connection
>   abort"**

[image]

- My API takes 60 Second to complete an operation.
- This is only happened in iPhones, not in simulators.

Please give me a solution for this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: alamofire default time interval is : 60 , if you want to reduce the time you can pass the timeout interval as your need, simulators does not through the  exact issue.

Comment: i have set time interval is : request.timeoutInterval = 15000 @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: what you mean are you set the 250 minutes for each calls ..?

Comment: Normal API also gives the same error when Time interval is default 60 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I think that iOS 12 close the connection before the last request returns a result when the app goes in background. you can use the following code to resolve your issue:

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    [self sendBackgroundDataToServer];

}

- (void) sendBackgroundDataToServer {
         UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
         bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
         }];

         NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
        [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lc.coordinate.latitude] forKey:@"floLatitude"];
        [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lc.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"floLongitude"];
        // send to server with a synchronous request


       // AFTER ALL THE UPDATES, close the task
       if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check and back to you.

Comment: Your method is not working for me because I don't want to call API in the background.     Alamofire give me an error when I call API and Lock mobile screen or Minimize application.

Comment: What is complete scenario of your issue? i.e whenever you came into foreground and you hit the Api then error came?

Comment: @AnkitSaini He will call the API, While the API is in progress, we will minimize the app or lock the screen. When we open the app again, it will show the alert message as above.

Comment: @VimalkumarN.M. Absolutely right. There is no solution. This error is from apple side as per this -> https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4279

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to the same question on Alamofire's GitHub page that I find useful:

> [...] this is an underlying system error that can happen when network requests are killed during backgrounding. I suggest you implement background tasks around your network requests to keep them alive long enough to complete while in the background. You can find thorough documentation on [Apple's dev forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85066). Once you properly handle that transition, the errors should stop, or give you a chance to properly cancel the requests.[

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Restart your iphone , the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found an accurate solution for this problem:

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        APIManager.shared.backgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }
```

In Your API Manager Class:

```
private lazy var backgroundManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let bundleIdentifier = "com.YourDomain.YourAppName"
        return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: bundleIdentifier + ".background"))
    }()

var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
    get {
        return backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler
    }
    set {
        backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
    }
}
```

How to Call API:

```
let backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
backgroundManager.session.configuration.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true
backgroundManager.startRequestsImmediately = true
backgroundManager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 180

backgroundManager.request(url, method: apiType, parameters: dict, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
                .responseJSON(queue: .main) { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in

     UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskIdentifier)

     switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):

            case .failure(_):

      }
}
```

Comment: Is this working fine for you? I have a scenario of deep linking, when I come back to the app, I am getting network connection lost. This is not happening frequently, but since this is related to payment task. I had to look into it.